# SqlCommand (CommandType Text) retrieve param collection

Tags: ado.net, sqlcommand, sqlcommandbuilder

Is there a way to get the parameter collection from `SqlCommand` when **CommandType = Text**?

For instance:

```
string MyDinamicSql = @"SELECT * FROM USERS where USERName = @Param1 and USERLogin=@Param2";
SqlCommand comand = connection.CreateCommand();
comand.CommandText = MyDinamicSql;
comand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

//Do something for fill comand.Parameters from MyDinamicSql...
```

I want a way to get a parameter collection with [@Param1,@Param2]... I don't know the sql queries (they are dynamic) and I want to get the parameters for my application to create them as input controls.

I can't do this with `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command)`, because it only works with stored procedures.

Thank you!

Comment: How are the SQL strings being generated? Are they being built up from code or are they coming from your users?

Comment: They were written without a place for parameter name's store... :-/ They came from users, and my app don't know the query parameters.

Comment: In delphi I had something like FetchParams (on ClientDataSet) when its engine parse sql and do this. But in C# I not found any like it.

Comment: So the reason why I asked is because you'll need to either parse it yourself, or getting a third party library. If you can control the way the SQL is constructed it would make parsing it yourself a little easier. I suspect that why parameters on data.stackexchange.com look like ##Param1##

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - until SQL Server parses the command, it's just a string.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to force sql server parse my command text to get a parameter collection?

Comment: SQL Server won't even try unless you give it parameters, sorry :(